# Move a [-] symbol with condition

Tags: r

I'm still learning R, and you guys have been so helpful with your educative answers.
So here is my issue, It might be very basic but i tried solutions with sub, gsub and casewhen, getting no results. I have a column with some numbers with [-] sign in the right. And if they have the - i would like to move it upfront.

```
col<- c("1.000","100-","12.000-","12.568-", "100","150","1.000.000-")
col2<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
A<-cbind(col2,col)
A<-as.data.frame(A)
```

Expected result:

```
col2<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
col<-c("1.000","-100","-12.000","-12.568", "100","150","-1.000.000")
A<-cbind(col2,col)
A<-as.data.frame(A)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```r
sub("(.*)-$", "-\\1", A$col)
#> [1] "1.000"      "-100"       "-12.000"    "-12.568"    "100"      "150"   
#> [7] "-1.000.000"
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly but could you explain a little about the logic so I can improve my coding?

Comment: @FenicoAlarcon sure. `sub` looks for a single match in each string of your character vector using regular expressions. The regular expression `(.*)-$` means "If the string ends with a `-`, match and capture all characters  in each string apart from the final `-` ". You then replace the matched characters with the replacement string, which is a `-` followed by `\\1` which means "all the captured characters in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write an ifelse that checks if the last character in the string is a dash and in that case paste it in front:

```
library(stringr)

A %>% 
  mutate(col_edit = ifelse(str_sub(col,-1,-1) == "-",
                           paste0("-",str_sub(col,1,-2)),
                           col))

  col2        col   col_edit
1    A      1.000      1.000
2    B       100-       -100
3    C    12.000-    -12.000
4    D    12.568-    -12.568
5    E        100        100
6    F        150        150
7    G 1.000.000- -1.000.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
A$col - str_replace(A$col, "^(.*)-$", "-\\1")
A$col
#[1] "1.000"      "-100"       "-12.000"    "-12.568"    "100"        "150"        "-1.000.000"
```